# How to fetch collection of Zuora Accounts using REST API

Tags: rest, pagination, zuora

I want to fetch all customer accounts from Zuora. Apart from [Exports](https://www.zuora.com/developer/api-reference/#tag/Exports) REST API, Is there any API available to fetch all accounts in a paginated list?

Answer (score 0):

This is the format I used to fetch revenue invoices, use this code and change the endpoint

````
import pandas as pd

# Set the sleep time to 10 seconds
sleep = 10

# Zuora OAUTH token URL
token_url = "https://rest.apisandbox.zuora.com/oauth/token"

# URL for the DataQuery
query_url = "https://rest.apisandbox.zuora.com/query/jobs"

# OAUTH client_id & client_secret
client_id = 'your client id'
client_secret = 'your client secret'

# Set the grant type to client credential
token_data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}

# Send the POST request for the OAUTH token
access_token_resp = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data,
                                      auth=(client_id, client_secret))

# Print the OAUTH token respose text
#print access_token_resp.text

# Parse the tokens as json data from the repsonse
tokens = access_token_resp.json()
#print "access token: " + tokens['access_token']

# Use the access token in future API calls & Add to the headers
query_job_headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokens['access_token']}

# JSON Data for our DataQuery
json_data = {
        "query": "select * from revenuescheduleiteminvoiceitem",
        "outputFormat": "JSON",
        "compression": "NONE",
        "retries": 3,
        "output": {
                "target": "s3"
        }
}

# Parse the JSON output
data = json.dumps(json_data)

# Send the POST request for the dataquery
query_job_resp = requests.post(query_url, data=data,
                                  headers=query_job_headers)
# Print the respose text
#print query_job_resp.text

# Check the Job Status

# 1) Parse the Query Job Response JSON data
query_job = query_job_resp.json()

# 2) Create the Job URL with the id from the response
query_job_url = query_url+'/'+query_job["data"]["id"]

# 3) Send the GETrequest to check on the status of the query
query_status_resp = requests.get(query_job_url, headers = query_job_headers)
#print query_status_resp.text

# Parse the status from teh response
query_status = query_status_resp.json()["data"]["queryStatus"]
#print ('query status:'+query_status)

# Loop until the status == completed
# Exit if there is an error
while (query_status != 'completed'): 
    time.sleep(sleep)
    query_status_resp = requests.get(query_job_url, headers = query_job_headers)
    #print query_status_resp.text
    query_status = query_status_resp.json()["data"]["queryStatus"]
    if (query_status == 'failed'):
        print ("query: "+query_status_resp.json()["data"]["query"]+' Failed!\n')
        exit(1)

# Query Job has completed
#print ('query status:'+query_status)


# Get the File URL
file_url = query_status_resp.json()["data"]["dataFile"]
print (file_url)```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Data Query or any queue-based solution like that, use [Zoql](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/Central_Platform/Query/ZOQL) instead.
*Note*! You need to know all fields from the Account object you need, the asterisk (`select *`) doesn't work here:

```
select Id, ParentId, AccountNumber, Name from Account
```

You may also add custom fields into your selection. You will get up to 200 records per page.